# Vanilla HTML+JS - Dynamic Interpolation?

Tags: javascript, html, interpolation, templating-engine

I know that in frameworks like Handlebars and ect. it is possible to write HTML similar to the following:

```
<span id="logged-on-username">{{username}}</span>
```

In this contrived example, a JS file loaded when on this page would return the value of a variable called username and interpolate it into the view template.

Is anything similar possible in vanilla HTML + JS?

Thanks in advance for anyone's time who happens to answer.

Comment: Yes, JS is used to manipulate the DOM to do things like update the page with new content. For example: `document.querySelector("#logged-on-username").textContent = "MyUserName";`

Comment: @slappy  I guess he meant to inject variables through template engine approach as he showed in the question.

Comment: @Kerematam: Oh, you mean he wants to target the curly braces?

Comment: @slappy Your code was perfect. I tested it and it worked for my needs and I will be using it in addition to the code given in the accepted answer.

Comment: Glad it helped. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this

```js
const content = {
  "username": "Fredy Kruger",
  "status": "Scary",
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("span.dynamic")].forEach(span => {
    const match = span.textContent.match(/{{(.*?)}}/)
    if (match.length === 2) span.innerText = content[match[1]]
  })
})
```

```html
Name: <span class="dynamic" id="logged-on-username">{{username}}</span><br/> 
Status: <span class="dynamic">{{status}}</span><br/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have selected this as the answer as it perfectly answers my question. This also shows me the logic that can possibly used to create my own template engine, which meets my needs. I would also like to thank @slappy who commented on the original post. His code is also very helpful and will be used.

Comment: May be a good idea to make the wildcard match non-greedy `{{{.*?}}}`, just in case there are multiple matches in a text node, like `{{username}} {{score}}`

Comment: @slappy except that will not work either since my code only handle one var per element